# Is there a preposition in Russian language like "of" in English?

Tags: одним-словом, предлоги

I'm trying to get the parallel preposition for "of" in Russian language and I'm really confused a little bit. I want it to explain to a Russian how to use "of" in an English sentence, but I can't find something that I know that it is really like "of" in the following contexts.

> This is the president **of** Russia.
>   This is the end **of** the show.
>   This is the bank **of** Moscow.
>   This car is **of** my mother.

I've checked the translation on Google Translate, and [this is](https://translate.google.com.ua/?um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#auto/ru/of) what I found... 
[image: Google Translate screenshot]

Comment: Don't use Goggle Translate as a dictionary! It is not intended to be a dictionary.

Comment: The choice of preposition is slightly arbitrary between languages. Usually, if you take a given preposition in one language, it never has a perfect overlap with a preposition in another language, but different prepositions are used in the target language to cover its uses (also, these prepositions have further uses which are covered by something else in your language). So, you should give up your expectation to find "the" preposition which translates your preposition, in this case and in others.

Answer (score 16):

No, there is no direct equivalent. 'Of' (indicating possession/containment) is usually rendered into Russian using the genitive case or possessive adjectives/pronouns.

> This is president of Russia. -- Это президент России. 
> This is the end of the show. -- Это конец шоу. 
> This is the bank of Moscow. -- Это банк Москвы. 
> This car is of my mother. -- Это машина моей матери.

There are only a few cases where 'of' can be rendered as **из**:

> Сделан **из** камня -- 'made **of** stone'
>
> Вилем II **из** Пернштейна -- 'William II **of** Pernstein'

Needless to say (or maybe not) that constructs such as 'to be proud of', 'to dispose of' are of a totally different kind and are rendered into Russian using other grammatical cases. Grammatical cases are a huge thing in Russian. You won't get far in your studies without them.

Comment: С "шоу" неудачный пример, несклоняемое существительное.

Comment: **Конец передачи** in the translation could cure the inclination problem. A small addition. Sometimes **'of+a noun'** is translated using an **adjective**: Prince of Wales -> принц _Уэльский_; a man of decision -> _решительный_ человек; wolf of Tambov -> _тамбовский_ волк.

Comment: @V.V. А может быть наоборот удачный? Показывает, что есть несклоняемые существительные.

Comment: worth pointing out (for those who are new to grammaitcal cases) that when it's translated with the preposition **из**, it governs Genitive as well

Comment: @V.V. Да, "шоу" в этом примере в родительном падеже. Просто у этого слова все падежи выглядят одинаково.

Comment: So how people in Russian normally learn the meaning of the preposition "of" if it's not in their original language? I believe that there is a way to understand it. Maybe you know something about that and you can share it.

Comment: @Influx I guess when someone learns a new language. He/she learns reusable expressions/blocks/patterns rather than replaces word-for-word in a sentence. Just like an English-speaking person learns Genitive case which doesn't exist in English.

Comment: @Influx they learn it on a case by case basis, but at the initial stages of language learning it's treated as possessive preposition first and foremost, as the learning progresses students naturally expand their knowledge of its uses

Comment: There are cases where *of* is rendered neither as *из* nor as a (preposition-less) genitive, for instance: *think of something else*, *very nice of you*, *died of an unknown disease*.

Comment: @AndriyM, Yes, those go into the 'proud of', 'dispose of' bucket in my answer: various verbs and adjectives using 'of' to govern other words.

Comment: Oh I see, I skimmed through the last paragraph and missed that point. I think categorising all the other cases together is a bit too much, though, as there are very different meanings of *of* among them. For instance, in each of my examples the *of* would be translated differently.